# Display different errors based on which submit button has been clicked in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, html, laravel

I hope you're all doing well and having a good festive season.  I wanted to post a question to find out how I can display the errors for a particular form in Laravel 5.1 based on what submit button has been clicked.  Here is some code to give a better explanation of what I'm trying to do.

```html
<form action="{{ url( '/auth/login' ) }}" id="login" method="post">
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="show validation-summary">
            ... display error container only when the login submit button has been clicked
        </div>
    @endif
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<form action="{{ url( '/auth/register' ) }}" id="register" method="post">
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="show validation-summary">
            ... display error container only when the register submit button has been clicked
        </div>
    @endif
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Currently both validation divs are displaying when clicking the Login or Register submit buttons, but I only want to display the validation div which relates to that form that was submitted.

Comment: Use a [named error bag](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#error-messages-and-views). You could do something like `$errors->first_form->first('email')` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Andrew that seems to be working but now I don't get the error messages back when doing a @foreach($errors->login as $error), even though the count($errors->login) > 0.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well you need to do `$errors->your_error_bag_name->first('the_error_name')`. It should work fine, at least it does for me. If you can't get it working, post the controller methods that take care of the returns too.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew I got it to work, I had to use '@foreach ($errors->my_named_error_bag->all() as $error)' I was only using '@foreach($errors->my_named_error_bag as $error)'.  Thanks alot for your quick responses and take care.

Comment: Cheers, glad to help.

Comment: @Andrew you may already be planning to do this, but you should post this as an answer. Comments can be deleted and your answer may help future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [named error bag](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#error-messages-and-views).

For example, in your controller you can do:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
    'some_input'        => 'required',
], [
    'some_input.required' => 'The input is required.',
]);

// ...some other code may go here

if($validator->fails())
{
    return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validator, 'named_error_bag');
}
```

To display the errors in your named error bag in the view you can do.

```
@if(!empty($errors->named_error_bag->first('error_name')))
    {{ $errors->named_error_bag->first('error_name') }}
@endif
```